# sqlite3_bind_blob when is safe to free memory?

Tags: c, sqlite

I have such working code:

```
const char sql[] = "INSERT INTO test (pk, geom) VALUES (?, ?)";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
sqlite3_prepare_v2 (handle, sql, strlen (sql), &stmt, NULL);

for (...) {
        sqlite3_reset (stmt);
        sqlite3_clear_bindings (stmt);
        int blob_size = ..;
        unsigned char *blob = malloc(blob_size);
        sqlite3_bind_int64 (stmt, 1, pk);
        sqlite3_bind_blob (stmt, 2, blob, blob_size, free);
        sqlite3_step (stmt);
}
```

I wonder is it possible to not allocate and free on every step of cycle?
If I pass `SQLITE_STATIC` instead of `free` to `sqlite3_bind_blob`
and call `free` after end of cycle is this code still become valid?

```
const char sql[] = "INSERT INTO test (pk, geom) VALUES (?, ?)";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
sqlite3_prepare_v2 (handle, sql, strlen (sql), &stmt, NULL);
int capacity = 1024;
unsigned char *blob = malloc(capacity);

for (...) {
        sqlite3_reset (stmt);
        sqlite3_clear_bindings (stmt);
        int blob_size = ..;
        if (capacity < blob_size) {
           blob = realloc(blob, blob_size);
           capacity = blob_size;
        }
        sqlite3_bind_int64 (stmt, 1, pk);
        sqlite3_bind_blob (stmt, 2, blob, blob_size, SQLITE_STATIC);
        sqlite3_step (stmt);
}
free(blob);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `SQLITE_STATIC` requires that the value stays valid as long as the statement might access it.

Your code should be valid; but to be sure, move the call to `sqlite3_clear_bindings()` (and the reset) to the end of the loop.

Comment: When you say “the end of the loop”, do you mean “the end of the loop body” (still inside the loop)? Or do you mean “after the loop” (outside the loop)? Either way, how does it help? `sqlite3_clear_bindings()` should have no effect in this context, since all parameters explicitly get new bindings before every call to `sqlite3_step()` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Question: **If I pass `SQLITE_STATIC` instead of `free` to `sqlite3_bind_blob` and call `free` after end of cycle is this code still become valid?**

Answer: **No.**

[SQLite documentation on `sqlite3_bind_blob()`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html):

> If the fifth argument has the value SQLITE_TRANSIENT, then SQLite makes its own private copy of the data immediately, before the sqlite3_bind_*() routine returns.

This implies that when the fifth argument does not have this value (in particular, when the fifth argument has the value `SQLITE_STATIC`), SQLite may still require the data after the routine returns. In that case, no guarantees are made about how long SQLite may require the data (except, presumably, SQLite will not require anything after `sqlite3_close()` is called).

Answer (score 0):

From the SQLite [docs](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html):

> The fifth argument to the BLOB and string binding interfaces is a destructor used to dispose of the BLOB or string after SQLite has finished with it. The destructor is called to dispose of the BLOB or string even if the call to bind API fails. If the fifth argument is the special value SQLITE_STATIC, then SQLite assumes that the information is in static, unmanaged space and does not need to be freed. If the fifth argument has the value SQLITE_TRANSIENT, then SQLite makes its own private copy of the data immediately, before the sqlite3_bind_*() routine returns.

If you're reallocating the memory, you should use `SQLITE_TRANSIENT`. That way SQLite won't make any assumptions about being able to rely on that memory, it will make its own copy.

Note that the docs don't say anything about *exactly* when the specified destructor (if any) is called -- only that it is called when SQLite is finished with the BLOB. If you don't want to use `SQLITE_TRANSIENT`, then you should *NOT* use `SQLITE_STATIC`, because SQLite may or may not assume that the memory is available when it actually isn't anymore.

Comment: I do not want to any extra copy, not important by me, or by sqlite